# Can SARS-COV2 strain competition be modelled by inter-species lotka volterra equations?

Tags: ecology, population-biology, epidemiology

Currently studying infectious diseases epidemiology and never studied ecology. But I was wondering if the interspecies Lotka Volterra equations could model and explain strain dominance.

r = could be the effective reproductive number of the virus;

x = prevalence of people currently infected with a certain strain;

alpha = formally is the inhibitive effect of species one on species two; Here I think they'd be equal to each other. if a strain infects someone, he or she cannot be infected by the other competing strain.

Finally K, which is in the ecological context, the carrying capacity defined as the maximum number of individuals of that species the ecosystem is able to accommodate, where the number of births is equal to that of deaths so for this case it may be defined as the prevalence of the strain where the number of infected individuals remain at an equilibrium i.e. every infected person infects, on average, one other person so the effective reproductive number = 1.

So for instance Omicron and Delta in the UK.
where it took omicron only one month to supplant delta as the dominant strain.

Comment: https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fmicb.2020.572487/full

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and see the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: In addition, note that "if a strain infects someone, he or she cannot be infected by the other competing strain" is unlikely to be true — one of the ways that viruses change occurs when different viruses infect the same cell. If you have evidence that this can't happen for coronaviruses, please add that to your question.

Comment: @tyersome its more parsimonious to assume that active infection with a particular strain will constrain another strain from establishing infection when exposed, given that the innate immune response is heightened making the respiratory tract inhospitable. And besides as far as we know human coronaviruses do not undergo antigenic drift. So what i really meant was once a person is infected and becomes symptomatic, they will not be able to be infected with the competing strain until the person becomes susceptible to the competing strain again (because of cross protection)

Comment: From everything I’ve read about SARS-CoV-2, it absolutely has experienced antigenic drift throughout the pandemic. Of course, the sensitivity of an existing immune response (or priming due to vaccine or a prior infection) to that drift is still an area of research. That said, the degree of vaccine escape by omicron (along with the many mutations relative to past variants) implies some amount of antigenic drift.

Comment: @Greenstick sorry I meant to say antigenic SHIFT not drift. Because tyersome was implying that coinfection of the same cell could produce genetically distinct strains, which is the definitely the case with flu but not so with human coronaviruses.

Comment: FWIW, coronaviruses can recombine too, just not in the same way as influenza.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably by "interspecies Lotka-Volterra equations" you mean the L-V *competition* equations (the predator-prey version is much better known).

Let's start with a two-strain epidemiological model without coinfection, i.e. a host can only be infected by one strain at a time:

$$
\begin{split}
S' & = S (-\beta_1 I_1 + \beta_2 I_2) \\
I_1' & = \beta_1 S I_1 - \gamma_1 I_1 \\
I_2' & = \beta_2 S I_2 - \gamma_2 I_2 \\
R' & = \gamma_1 I_1 + \gamma_2 I_2
\end{split}
$$

This doesn't look like the L-V competition equations, which reach some sort of competitive equilibrium, because there is no renewal of the "resource" (in this case, susceptible people); the epidemic runs its course and dies out. However, we could allow *waning immunity* and make an SIRS model so that the recovered people eventually become susceptible again:

$$
\begin{split}
S' & = S (-\beta_1 I_1 + \beta_2 I_2) + \phi R \\
R' & = \gamma_1 I_1 + \gamma_2 I_2 - \phi R
\end{split}
$$

(the $I$ equations stay the same). This is getting closer, but still doesn't quite match the LV equations. We have to take one more step (which is actually away from the direction of a realistic COVID-19 model) and allow recovering people to become susceptible *immediately* (i.e. no immunity, as in a disease like gonorrhea), so that we get:

$$
\begin{split}
S' & = S (-\beta_1 I_1 + \beta_2 I_2) + \gamma_1 I1 + \gamma_2 I_2 \\
I_1' & = \beta_1 S I_1 - \gamma_1 I_1 \\
I_2' & = \beta_2 S I_2 - \gamma_2 I_2 \\
\end{split}
$$

This is an "SIS" model. In the SIS and SIRS models the population size is constant, so in particular for the SIS model we can write $S = N -  I_1 - I_2$ and drop the redundant $S$ equation so we get

$$
\begin{split}
I_1' & = \beta_1 (N - I_1 - I_2) I_1 - \gamma_1 I_1 \\
I_2' & = \beta_2 (N - I_1 - I_2) I_2 - \gamma_2 I_2 \\
\end{split}
$$

which we can rearrange to

$$
I_1' = (\beta_1 N - \gamma_1) I_1  - \beta_1 I_1^2 - \beta_1 I_1 I_2
$$

and a symmetric equation (exchanging $_1$ and $_2$ subscripts) for $I_2$. We can rewrite this as

$$
I_1' = (\beta_1N-\gamma_1) I_1 \left( 1 - \frac{I_1 + I_2}{N-\gamma_1/\beta_1}\right)
$$

Comparing this with  (one particular parameterization of) the L-V competition equations,

$$
N_1' = r_1 \left( 1 - \frac{N_1 + \alpha_{21} N_2}{K_1} \right)
$$

We see that these are equivalent with $r_1 \equiv \beta_1 N - \gamma_1$, $K_1 = N-\gamma_1/\beta_1$, $\alpha_{21} = 1$.

A few general comments:

- a lot of your guesses are right. For this case the two strains are equivalent (each occupies one unit of "resource", i.e. one susceptible host), so $\alpha_{12} = \alpha_{21} = 1$.
- the *r* in the L-V equations is a growth *rate* (i.e. rate of exponential increase when rare), not a growth multiplier per generation ($R$ or ${\cal R}$), so it's $\beta N - \gamma$ (with units of 1/time) rather than $\beta N/\gamma$ (unitless)
- The carrying capacity is indeed the number of hosts infected by $I_1$ at a monoculture equilibrium, i.e. $N ( 1- 1/{\cal R}_{0,1})$
- in order to have a usefully realistic model of COVID-19 competition, you would probably need some of the following:

  - go back to a short time scale and forget about the detailed equivalence with the L-V model
  - allow for imperfect cross-immunity, i.e. one of omicron's big advantages is that it appears to be able to reinfect people who have recovered from delta while the converse seems less likely (although that is much less well known)
- the assumption of no co-infection seems like a reasonable simplification, given that the prevalence (fraction of the population infected) is low relative to the population size even at the peak of a COVID-19 spike (i.e., a small percentage of the population has an active infection)

Comment: Wow, thank you! I wonder if there is an established field devoted to modelling infectious diseases epidemiology as ecological phenomena, I am defnintely interested to dig deeper! Thank you again for the answer!

Comment: There are very close connections between ecological and epidemiological modeling. For example, Robert May <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_May,_Baron_May_of_Oxford> was both a theoretical ecologist and an  eminent epidemiological modeler. One other example: Martcheva, Maia, Benjamin M Bolker, and Robert D Holt. “Vaccine-Induced Pathogen Strain Replacement: What Are the Mechanisms?” Journal of the Royal Society Interface 5, no. 18 (January 6, 2008): 3–13. https://doi.org/10.1098/rsif.2007.0236.

Comment: I'm wondering now why strictly adhering to the L-V model would not result in a useful/realistic COVID-19 model for predicting strain competition. Is it because of practical factors such as vaccination and lockdowns (and other interventions) or is it inherent to the model itself?

Comment: The most unrealistic aspect is that it assumes there is no natural immunity after recovery.